# How can I use a rnd generated in a loop in an if statement

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, variable-assignment, variable-declaration

I have to write a program that simulates 2 dice rolls 4 times, if the 2 dice end up as the same number a certain multiplier needs to be increased by 10, so far I've managed to simulate dice rolls by using rnd.next in a loop. However I don't know how to use the randomly generated numbers outside of the loop

Here I generated the 2 random numbers (dice rolls)

```
int valuestone1;
            int valuestone2;
            int multiplier = 0;
            int add10 = 10;
            int multipliernew;
            for (int forassignment = 1; forassignment <= 4; forassignment++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(valuestone1 = rnd.Next(1, 7));
                Console.WriteLine(valuestone2 = rnd.Next(1, 7));
            }
```

And here I tried to use them to add points to the multiplier if 2 of the numbers were the same

```
if (valuestone1 == valuestone2)
            {
                multipliernew= multiplier + add10;
            }
```

However it gives the message "use of unassigned local variable" on the valuestones.
How do I make this work?

Comment: when creating value just assign them value = 0, so it will not give you error.
int valuestone1 = 0;
int valuestone2 = 0;

Answer (score 1):

You can *store* generated values in a *collection*, say `List<Tuple<int, int>>`:

```
  List<Tuple<int, int>> rolls = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

  ...

  for (int forassignment = 1; forassignment <= 4; forassignment++)
    rolls.Add(Tuple.Create(rnd.Next(1, 7), rnd.Next(1, 7)));
```

Or you can create and fill the collection in one go with a help of  *Linq*

```
  List<Tuple<int, int>> rolls = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 4)
    .Select(i => Tuple.Create(rnd.Next(1, 7), rnd.Next(1, 7))) 
    .ToList();
```

Now let's use them:

```
  // Printing out 
  foreach (var roll in rolls)
    Console.WriteLine($"{roll.Item1} {roll.Item2}");

  // multipliernew computation
  foreach (var roll in rolls)
    if (roll.Item1 == roll.Item2)
      multipliernew = multiplier + add10;
```